# How to avoid wrong variable name interpretation in perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I want to replace apache configuration file's MinSpareThreads directive value from 75 to 125.

I wrote perl one-liner code like below.

```
perl -pi.$(date +%Y%m%d) -e 's;MinSpareThreads(\s+)(\d+);MinSpareThreads$1125;g' httpd-mpm.conf
```

However it outputs below result.

```
root@8c659a9d5907:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra# diff httpd-mpm.conf.20180130 httpd-mpm.conf
46c46
<     MinSpareThreads         75
---
>     MinSpareThreads
63c63
<     MinSpareThreads         75
---
>     MinSpareThreads
83c83
<     MinSpareThreads         25
---
>     MinSpareThreads
97c97
<     MinSpareThreads          5
---
>     MinSpareThreads
```

It seems $1 is unintendedly recognized as $1125.
$1125 doesn't exist. So above result is shown.

Do you know any way to avoid above wrong interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a Perl variable in a context where its name won't be distinguished from the surrounding text, you can put the name (not including the sigil) inside `{ ... }`. So, instead of having `$1125`, you would have `${1}125`.